# UIView over a UIView over a UIView - Is there a better way to arrange that?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have more then 6 `UIView`s inside my `ViewController` that I show on and off using alpha. Is there a way to organize them in a way that everything is accessible to changes in the interface builder beside containers? (I'm using storyboards)

Right now if I want to change something in the first `UIView` in the hierarchy I need to move all the `UIView`s above it to the side of the `ViewController` before I can click on it and change what I need.

Comment: Does each of these 6 views have its own subviews that you want to edit?  Or do you just want to change properties of one of the 6 views?

Comment: You can use the “outline” view, at the left of the Interface Builder canvas, to select each view easily (specially if you give them names).  The outline can be expanded to be easier to use in the icon in the lower left of the canvas.

Comment: Each view got his own subviews. The outline solution won't help if I want to move with a mouse drag a subview of a view that's under another view.

Comment: You can use the "outline" view, drag the view you want to edit to the bottom (bring the layer on top). Edit the subviews in IB, after you are done, drag the view back to its position in "outline" view again.

Answer (score 0):

Create the views outside of the UIViewController's view hierarchy in the same XIB. Then add or remove them to the main view whenever needed. Looks a lot cleaner.i used that approach lately and it's great for complicated hierarchies.

Comment: Yes, or they can just retain them in an array and add/remove from that array. I like the Xib solution

Comment: How can I do that if I'm using storyboards? The interface builder won't let me drag just a `UIView` to the canvas. It has to be a `UIViewController`.

Comment: You can mix using XIB files and storyboards actually but it will bring some complexity to your code. Just think over the tradeoffs of each approach and decide which suits your work style better.